# Facebook Like Box won't appear, despite code being in place

Tags: css, html, facebook-like, jscript

I have the following code in place, but have problems in getting the Facebook Like box to appear in the first place. Can someone help point out where I'm wrong. Have used Venus William's fan page as an example. All rights to the content goes to her.

Thanks much.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <title>Your Wishes</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/grid_24.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/style.css">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans+Narrow:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Great+Vibes' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
    <script>(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <section id="content"><div class="ic"></div>
        <div class="container_24">
            <div class="grid_24">
                <div class="top-1">
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <h4><strong>Your</strong> wishes:</h4>
                    <div class="fb-like-box" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/VenusWilliams" data-width="1600" data-height="700" data-colorscheme="light" data-show-faces="true" data-header="true" data-stream="true" data-show-border="false"></div>
                </div>
            </div>  
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
    </section> 

     <footer>
      <p><strong>© 2013  </strong><br> <a class="link" href="" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"></a> Designed and developed by . 2013.</p>
      <div class="soc-icons"><a href="#"><img src="" alt=""></a><a href="#"><img src="images/icon-2.png" alt=""></a><a href="#"><img src="" alt=""></a></div></div>
  </footer> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: sometimes it happens because of some pop-up blocker plugins installed in browser...have you checked it in different browser?

Comment: Yes, I did. Faced the same issue though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using a local server (WAMP), checked your code and it runs fine....
Please check this link  [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/logintomyk/3mzsL/)

If you can see it in the above demo link, then your code is fine but you have some browser or server specific issues!! :)

This particular portion of JS may look like non-server required code, but it calls a server response for which you need to execute the code from server :

```
 (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

Comment: Wow. Never thought of the server response aspect. I'm using a free web hosting service, and am developing the website on just a laptop. Luckily they have the service, and it's free! Thanks Mayank. Much appreciated.

Comment: And just so that other users aren't confused. I forgot that this line will actually look for file on the server `code`js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1"; `code`. For the purpose of running from a file, just add 'https' before the connect.facebook line.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running it directly from the file? Facebook snippets use Ajax calls to display Facebook page contents, so you need to run your page from a webserver - even a devserver (localhost) should work.

Comment: Actually I am running it directly from the file. Will try a devserver.